# Laravel Ajax image upload with preview not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, image-uploading, malsup-ajax-form

The form for uploading the image using Laravel Form Facade

```
{{Form:: open(['route'=>'jcrop.store', 'method'=>'post','id'=>'upload','role'=>'form-role', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])}}
 @include('backend.admin.jcrop.general._form',['submitButton'=>'Save Values'])
{{Form:: close()}}
```

The form which is included...

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form:: label('title','Title')}}
    {{Form:: text('title',null,['placeholder'=>'Enter Title', 'class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form:: label('rank','Rank')}}
    {{Form:: number('rank',null,['placeholder'=>'Enter Rank', 'class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form:: label('image','Image')}}
    {{Form:: file('image',null,['placeholder'=>'Enter Rank', 'class'=>'form-control', 'id'=> 'image'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form:: label('status','Status:')}}
    {!! Form::radio('status', '1', 'true')!!} Active
    {!! Form::radio('status', '0')!!} De-Active
</div>

{{Form:: button($submitButton,['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>'submit'])}}
{{Form:: button('Reset',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','name'=>'reset','type'=>'reset'])}}
```

The script which uploads image using malsupform plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        var options= {
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,
            success:    showResponse,
            dataType: 'json'
        };
            $("#image").change(function(){
            $("#upload").ajaxForm(options).submit();
        });
    });

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options){
        $("#validation-errors").hide().empty();
        return true;
    }

    function showResponse(response, statusText, xhr, $form){
        if(response.success==false)
        {

            var arr= response.errors;
            $.each(arr, function(index, value){
                if(value.length=!0){
                    $("#validation-errors").append('<div class="alert alert-danger">+value+</div');
                }
            });
            $("#validation-errors").show();
        }else{
            console.log(response.file);
            $("#output").html("<img src='"+response.file+"'/>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The routes to handle the upload and store methods.

```
Route::resource('jcrop', 'Admin\JcropController');
```

The Controller which handles the upload and returns the json format of  the data.

This is the Controller file in which I have declared some protected variable.

```
protected $view_path    = 'backend.admin.jcrop';
protected $imagePath    = '\public\uploads\jcrop';
protected $imageUrl     = 'uploads\jcrop';
```

The Controller Function which handles the upload and the returns the json format of the data..

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image= $this->saveImage($request->file('image'));
```

Here I have made a simple function called saveImage() which uploads the image and returns the uploaded file

```
            $file= base_path(). $this->imagePath.'/' .$image->getFileName();
            if($image){
                return response()->json(['success'=>'true', 'file'=>$file]);
        }
      }
         }
```

The function which handles the upload is...

```
protected function saveImage($image)
    {
        $filename= $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename= pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $file= $filename. '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload= $image->move(base_path().$this->imagePath, $file);
        return $upload;
    }
```

Everything is working fine except when the data is returned i see

```
        Not allowed to load local resource:
```

In chrome and FireFox as well. Please help me sort out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `saveImage()` return. Instead of `base_path()`, try using `url('/')`. `base_path()` returns server path not the URL.

```
$file= url('public/uploads/jcrop').$image->getFileName();
```

Comment: Yes it worked  but in the view the image is still not loaded and when on inspecting the image i see image not found on chrome console and upon clicking it to see on new tab I get not found http exception.....what's the reason behind this???

Comment: @Ravi Can you please provide what is image url looks like

Comment: laravelproject.dev/public/uploads/jcrop/{filename}

Comment: @Ravi Did you double check whether file exists in the folder?